# Is it possible to get cursor location using word web addin

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have a requirement where i need to insert data in word document based on cursor position. Is there any methods available to get cursor location

Comment: Have you read through the Office and the Word JS API documentation? And looked at on-line examples? This is a very basic thing... Show code you've tried and explain how it's not working. Also specify the version of Word (the Word API set) you're targeting.

Comment: Hi cindey i read the office and word api documentation and i didnt find any thing to get the cursor position.i am using word api 1.3

Comment: Look for the term `Selection`

Comment: Hi Cindy i need to track the location of the cursor based on cursor location i want to fire an event how selection will help here...

Comment: Please help me with any sample to understand

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#getselection--), you have to get the Selection (the curser is an empty selection), and can then insert text before or after the Selection.

```
let cursorOrSelection = context.document.getSelection();
context.load(cursorOrSelection);
await context.sync();
cursorOrSelection.insertText("Important text to insert", Word.InsertLocation.end);
await context.sync();
```

The possible insert locations are listed in the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.insertlocation?view=word-js-preview)

If you need to be sure that there is currently no selection, only a curser, you'd need to check `isEmpty` on the range `cursorOrSelection`. For further infos on what you can do with the range, refer to the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview)